# GraphQL query using TypeORM entity

Tags: javascript, graphql, typeorm

I am learning `graphql` and combining it with `typeorm`. I wrote a query with `graphql` and was wondering if this is the correct way to combine the `typeorm` entity and the `graphql` type for the same entity. Or is there a way for me to use the `typeorm` entity instead of the `graphql` type as the return value?

The `typeorm` entity and the `graphql` type have the exact same fields, essentially the are exactly the same. Just one is defined as a `graphql` type and the other is using the `typeorm` decorators.

I am also not sure how this magic is returning a `TestType` from a `Promise<Test>`. Where `TestType` is a `graphql` type and `<Test>` is a `typeorm` entity.

```
import {GraphQLFieldConfig, GraphQLNonNull} from "graphql/type/definition";
import {TestType} from "../type/TestType";
import {GraphQLID} from "graphql";
import {IGraphQLContext} from "../IGraphQLContext";

export const Test: GraphQLFieldConfig<any, IGraphQLContext, any> = {
    // notice the type to return here is the graphql type
    type: new GraphQLNonNull(TestType),
    description: "A query for a test",
    args: {
        id: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
            description: "The ID for the desired test"
        }
    },
    async resolve (source, args, context) {
        // getTest(...) here returns a promise<Test> where Test is a typeorm entity
        return context.db.testDAO.getTest(args.id);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to ditch the attempt to use typeorm and went with [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/).

Answer (score 2):

If you’re looking for the magic of Prisma (autogenerated DB and schema), but also the flexibility of hosting your APIs and having access to the models and resolvers so that you can perform custom actions, you should check out [Warthog](https://www.github.com/goldcaddy77/warthog).  It’s a Node.js GraphQL API framework written in TypeScript where you set up resolvers and data models, and it auto-generates your entire schema with opinionated pagination, filtering, etc... similar to Prisma’s conventions.  It’s not as feature-rich as Prisma, but it gives you a lot more control.  You can check out [warthog-starter](https://github.com/goldcaddy77/warthog-starter), which will get you up and running quickly.

Disclaimer: I’m the author of Warthog

Comment: Thanks, i will check it out.